# included layout in coordinate layout button click not working

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have one coordinate layout with tabs. In that coordinate layout I included one layout as per my requirement. Everything is working fine, but that included layout has one Imageview and Textview. I gave click action for ImageView and visibility gone for textview programatically. Imageview click action is not working. I tried so many ways. Only for that imageview action not happening. And one tab has a linear layout and other tab has recyclerview. Linear layout tab scrolling not working properly. For recycler view coordinate layout property working fine.This is my layout file.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/btn_bg"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    >

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_me"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"

                            android:gravity="end">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/me_Back"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_backnew" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_continue"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Continue"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:visibility="invisible" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/download" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/camera" />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rlProgress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Yamuna"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFriendsCount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="10 Friends"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:background="@color/light_grey" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_19sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_19sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvEmail"

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="yamuna@gmail.com"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvMobile"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:text="9986086918"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Koramangala"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pencil"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@color/light_grey" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/header"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:src="@drawable/test"
                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/btn_bg"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabTextColor="#000000" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <!--<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/shadow_prelollipop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_shadow" />
-->

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_head"
            layout="@layout/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Please forgive me for my basic question, help me out of this. Thanks In advance.

Comment: What look like your layout need? Attach layout snapshot , then help you make as per requirement with some change.

Comment: Yes i added my screenshot of my output

Comment: So, above title bar and tab at bottom right?

Comment: Yes... that tittle bar back button onclick  action not working

Comment: OK.. After some minutes will give you result just find and check solution.

Comment: And one more thing do you require viewpager or not?

Comment: Better to use `BottomNavigationBar` like this in example: http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/

Comment: No , nowi cant use this bottom navigation. Any way i dont have any issues with bottom bar. I have problem with top toolbar back button onclick

Comment: If I add that same image view below rl photo layout id then that onclick is working... I am not getting what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is the issue. I already added one toolbar with collapse mode pin and again i am trying to add one more toolbar with back button. So old toolbar overlapping this new toolbar and action not happened. So i disable the old toolbar and gave pinmode to new toolbar and resolved my problem.

Thanks.